# Webhook call occurs in a delay.How to make the webhook call run in backend as the user clicks payment button

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks, .net-core-2.0

I have a webhook integrated which works fine. But I also have an Ajax call which runs on click of button to create a customer in stripe as well in my system database. The webhook call runs slow i.e when I complete inserting into my database the webhook call occurs for the customer.create event.How to run the webhook on click of that particular submit payment button.So that both the calls run parallely and I get the charge object quickly

Comment: The webhook call that you receive is outside of your control, Stripe calls your service in an asynchronous flow, so you won't be able to tie it to your own submit. You can however either rely on that solely, or add some metadata to your customer (Which you will get back on the webhook) and that could be used to identify the customer on both calls / events.

Comment: Ok but Is there a way  that I can let my website keep loading until my particular customer's details are stored properly from webhook to my system database.

Comment: There is. You can use a [polling solution](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-polling) or through [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications) in both cases there will be work on the client and server side to get this going. Disclaimer: these 2 are not the only solutions to this.